# Synchronous input update with selected digit in HTML/JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to implement a customised input that can use left or right arrow key to select the digit and use up/down arrow key to increment/decrement the digit. Here's the code in jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/uk5t3z4d/48/. However, I have two problems:

1. I cannot add digit using the number pad, the input always stays at X.XX
2. When I use another function I wrote (parseLocalFloat which is commented out), the output stops displaying anything, and I cannot use the left and right key to select the digit etc.

How can I overcome these two issues? Please shed a light on me, thanks!

### HTML

```
<div class="display" id="out"></div>

<div class="form-group">
  <label for="comment">value:</label>
  <input class="form-control" type="text" value="0.00" id="in"></input>
</div>
```

### JavaScript

```
function createSelection(field, start, end) {
    if( field.createTextRange ) {
        var selRange = field.createTextRange();
        selRange.collapse(true);
        selRange.moveStart('character', start);
        selRange.moveEnd('character', end);
        selRange.select();
    } else if( field.setSelectionRange ) {
        field.setSelectionRange(start, end);
    } else if( field.selectionStart ) {
        field.selectionStart = start;
        field.selectionEnd = end;
    }
}      


function getLocalDecimalSeparator() {
    var n = 1.1;
    return n.toLocaleString().substring(1,2);
}

function parseLocalFloat(num) {
    return +(num.replace(getLocalDecimalSeparator(), '.'));
}

var inputBox = document.getElementById('in');

//var inputBox = parseLocalFloat(document.getElementByID('in').value);
inputBox.onkeyup = function(){
    document.getElementById('out').innerHTML = inputBox.value;
}

$('#in').on("keydown", function(e){
    var gotCode = false;
    var curPos = this.selectionStart;
    var endPos = this.selectionEnd;
    if(curPos !== endPos) {
        createSelection(this, curPos, curPos+1);
    }
    // get the position 
    if(e.keyCode == 37){
        curPos--;
        gotCode=true;
    }
    if(e.keyCode == 39){
        curPos++;
        gotCode=true;
    }
    var before = $(this).val().substring(0,curPos);
    var after = $(this).val().substring(curPos+1);
    var cur = Number($(this).val().substring(curPos, curPos+1));
    // avoid adding extra stuff 
    if(curPos < $(this).val().length) {
        if(e.keyCode == 38) {
           cur++;
           if(cur > 9) cur = 0;
           $(this).val(before + '' + cur + '' + after);
           gotCode=true;
        }
        if(e.keyCode == 40) {
            cur--;
            if(cur < 0) cur = 9;
            $(this).val(before + '' + cur + '' + after);
            gotCode=true;
        }
    }

    if(!gotCode) {
        e.preventDefault();
        return false;
    }

    var field = this;
    window.setTimeout(function(){
          createSelection(field, curPos, curPos+1);
    }, 10);

});
```

Answer (score 0):

For #1:

```
if(!gotCode) {
    e.preventDefault();
    return false;
}
```

ensures that if `gotCode` is false the default event (which in this case is the default `keydown` event) will not occur.

`gotCode` only seems to be true if `keyCode` is equal to `37`, `38`, `39`, or `40` (the arrow keys). You are essentially preventing the other keys (like number keys) from having any effect on the `textBox`.

You probably would like to enable the number keys (when shift or caps aren't on) and number pad keys.

Additionally, you may want to check that the `cur` is a number (and not `.`) before attempting to increment or decrement its value.

You could do:

```
var isNumberKey = (
        (  e.keyCode >= 48     //is more than or equal to 0 key
        && e.keyCode <= 57     //is less than or equal to 9 key
        && !e.shiftKey)        //shift key or cap key not on
    || (   e.keyCode >= 96     //more than or equal to 0 key in number pad
        && e.keyCode <= 105)); //less than or equal to 9 key in number pad
if(!gotCode && !isNumberKey) { //not arrow key or number key
    console.log(e);
    e.preventDefault();
    return false;
}
```

For #2:

```
var inputBox = parseLocalFloat(document.getElementByID('in').value);
```

is setting `inputBox` to whatever `parseLocalFloat` returns which happens to be a number.

This is problematic because you then attempt to attach a `keyUp` event to that number instead of the `inputBox`:

```
inputBox.onkeyup = function(){
    document.getElementById('out').innerHTML = inputBox.value;
}
```

You may want to instead call `parseLocalFloat` on the number and set the `out` textBox's value to that:

```
var inputBox = document.getElementById('in');
inputBox.onkeyup = function(){
    document.getElementById('out').innerHTML = parseLocalFloat(inputBox.value);
}
```

```js
function createSelection(field, start, end) {
    if( field.createTextRange ) {
        var selRange = field.createTextRange();
        selRange.collapse(true);
        selRange.moveStart('character', start);
        selRange.moveEnd('character', end);
        selRange.select();
    } else if( field.setSelectionRange ) {
        field.setSelectionRange(start, end);
    } else if( field.selectionStart ) {
        field.selectionStart = start;
        field.selectionEnd = end;
    }
}      


function getLocalDecimalSeparator() {
    var n = 1.1;
    return n.toLocaleString().substring(1,2);
}
  
function parseLocalFloat(num) {
    return +(num.replace(getLocalDecimalSeparator(), '.'));
}

var inputBox = document.getElementById('in');
// var inputBox = parseLocalFloat(document.getElementByID('in').value);
inputBox.onkeyup = function(){
    document.getElementById('out').innerHTML = parseLocalFloat(inputBox.value);
}

$('#in').on("keydown", function(e){
    var gotCode = false;
    var curPos = this.selectionStart;
 var endPos = this.selectionEnd;
    if(curPos !== endPos) {
        createSelection(this, curPos, curPos+1);
    }
    // get the position 
    if(e.keyCode == 37){
        curPos--;
        gotCode=true;
    }
    if(e.keyCode == 39){
        curPos++;
        gotCode=true;
    }
    var $thisVal = $(this).val();
    var before = $thisVal.substring(0,curPos);
    var after = $thisVal.substring(curPos+1);
    var cur = Number($thisVal.substring(curPos, curPos+1));
    // avoid adding extra stuff 
    if(curPos < $thisVal.length && !isNaN(cur)) {
        if(e.keyCode == 38) {
            cur++;
            if(cur > 9) cur = 0;
            $(this).val(before + '' + cur + '' + after);
            gotCode=true;
        }
        if(e.keyCode == 40) {
            cur--;
            if(cur < 0) cur = 9;
            $(this).val(before + '' + cur + '' + after);
            gotCode=true;
        }
    }
    var isNumberKey = ((e.keyCode >= 48 && e.keyCode <= 57 && [16, 20].indexOf(e.keyCode) == -1 && !e.shiftKey) || (e.keyCode >= 96 && e.keyCode <= 105));
    if(!gotCode && !isNumberKey) {
        console.log(e);
        e.preventDefault();
        return false;
    }
    
    var field = this;
    window.setTimeout(function(){
          createSelection(field, curPos, curPos+1);
    }, 10);
    
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="display" id="out"></div>

<div class="form-group">
  <label for="comment">value:</label>
  <input class="form-control" type="text" value="0.00" id="in"></input>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi, could you please explain further how do I solve the second problem? Thank.

Comment: I added some more explanation and some working code to the answer. Let me know if the answer requires more explanation..

Comment: Thanks for you help Moishe!

Answer (score 0):

as for the "get number keys to work":

as stated you need to add the keys you want to support:

```
if(e.keyCode >= 48 && e.keyCode <= 57)  {
        var num = e.keyCode - 48; // 0=48; 9=59
        $(this).val(before + '' + num + '' + after);
        gotCode = true;
        e.preventDefault(); // otherwise a new number is added as well
    }
```

(this needs to come before the if (!gotCode) ... )

as for the customFloat: the the response from Moishe

Comment: Hi Niko, I try to make a some changes but customFloat still doesn't work. [link](http://jsfiddle.net/uk5t3z4d/64/) Could you give help me with it?

Comment: i updated the jsfiddle so it works now (http://jsfiddle.net/uk5t3z4d/70/) - you should avoid mixing jquery with "plain" javascript dom - that looks ugly. Then, the second issue is, that you "float code" was never executed (it must be within an event function), and since we prevent the default handling in the control - you must manually trigger the "change" event.

Comment: Hi Niko, I updated the jsfiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/uk5t3z4d/110/). What I want to do is when number gets to 9 and increment, it automatically increment the previous digit. I tried to do this by the function 'smallestDecimalUnit' but sometimes it works but sometimes doesn't. Also, I add the input for '.' but somehow when I type '.' it appears as '..' Could you have a look and give me some ideas?